# Datepicker with month and year only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I would like to have a datepicker where user can select only the month and year from the datepicker and i also need to restrict the next datepicker with selected month and year from previous datepicker..

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sean answer is pretty good, if you want to disable day selecting as well, you might use a different approach, you can see the result in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gL7uW/12/):

Calendar is hidden, so you can only choose month and year. When selecting a date in  first datepicker, minDate of second datepicker is getting adapted.

**EDIT**

jQuery datepicker has seriously problems when dateformat doesn't provide a day. I changed th code to make it work. Only thing is when opening a datepicker, I have to convert the date to a suitable format. Have a look at the new fiddle.

HTML:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="first-datepicker"/></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="second-datepicker"/></p>
```

CSS:

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar,
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-current
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#first-datepicker').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        setMyDate(inst);
    },
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        saveMyDate(inst);

        var secondDatePicker = $('#second-datepicker').data('datepicker');
        var dateSetted = secondDatePicker.input.data('date-setted');

        setMyDate(secondDatePicker);

        secondDatePicker.input.datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 0));     

        if (dateSetted == true) {
            saveMyDate(secondDatePicker);
        };
    }
});

$('#second-datepicker').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        setMyDate(inst);
    },
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        saveMyDate(inst);
    }
});

function saveMyDate(inst) {
    inst.selectedDay = 1;
    inst.input.data('year', inst.selectedYear);
    inst.input.data('month', inst.selectedMonth);
    inst.input.data('day', inst.selectedDay );

    var date = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
    inst.input.datepicker('setDate', date );
    formatDate(inst, date);
    inst.input.data('date-setted', true);
};

function setMyDate(inst) {
    var dateSetted = inst.input.data('date-setted');

    if (dateSetted == true) {
        var year = inst.input.data('year');
        var month = inst.input.data('month');
        var day = inst.input.data('day');

        var date = new Date(year, month, day);
        inst.input.datepicker('setDate', date );
    };
};

function formatDate(inst, date) {
    var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM - yy', date);
inst.input.val(formattedDate);
};
```

Comment: Actually if you ask me, your answer is a mile ahead of mine =]

Comment: Hi Simon,
Thanks for your reply.
I checked your code with the link you gave.

Its nice. But when i add dateformat like `dateFormat: 'MM - yy'` in the options it failed to produce the correct result what i'm expecting to get.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simon! Awesome!! Its working.. Sorry for the very late response. you are rocking!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this monthpicker jquery widget : https://github.com/lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the jQuery datepicker to only allow the user to select certain dates, in this case we could restrict it to the first of the month:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disableDaysExceptFirst
})

function disableDaysExceptFirst(date) {
    if (date.getDate() != 1) {
        return [false, date.getDate().toString() + "_day"];
    }
    return [true, ""];
}
```

You can also modify the options to display the date differently:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/yy'
});
```

Combine the two and we get:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disableDaysExceptFirst,
    dateFormat: 'mm/yy'
})

function disableDaysExceptFirst(date) {
    if (date.getDate() != 1) {
        return [false, date.getDate().toString() + "_day"];
    }
    return [true, ""];
}
```

You can also use this to restrict your second datepicker:

```
var restrictedMonth = parseInt($("#myFirstDatePicker").text().split("/")[0]); //replace myFirstDatePicker with the HTML ID of the text input your datepicker is attached to

$("#myFirstDatePicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disableAllExceptCurrentMonth,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' //swap mm and dd for US dates
});

function disableAllExceptCurrentMonth(date) {
    if (date.getMonth() != restrictedMonth) {
        return [false, date.getDate().toString() + "_day"];
    }
    return [true, ""];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can work in html5 i would suggest to use the new month input support for newer browser

simply use  and let the magic happen.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/month

Comment: Does not work with Firefox (bug open for 6 years now). Doesn't work with Safari either.

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker can show month and year only without using css

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}?
```

You can do like this

```
var dp=$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    startView: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});

dp.on('changeMonth', function (e) {    
   //do something here
   alert("Month changed");
});
```

Documentation [here](https://qawithexperts.com/article/bootstrap/showing-month-and-year-only-in-bootstrap-datepicker/292)