# How to set only month picker in pickadate.js

Tags: javascript

I implemented the date picker in my code. I only need month and year. I have to remove date in calendar.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
selectMonths: true, 
selectYears:10, 
max: [2017]
});
```

Comment: Pickadate.js does not currently support this however the dev (a few years back) said they would consider:

https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/117

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datepicker with month and year only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681837/datepicker-with-month-and-year-only)

Comment: @TariqB. not really a dupe I'd say, but definitely worth OP checking it out